# Standard way to make server independent wordpress urls in editor?

Tags: wordpress, url, post, shortcode

When uploading images or linking pages in wordpress WYSIWYG editor the default behaviour is that wordpress generates the links using the siteurl database attribute. This becomes a hassle when building the sites' content on a test server or in a subfolder and then moving it to it's final place.

For example inserting an image generates this html on my dev server or production server temporary subfolder:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-60" title="bigcircuits" src="http://<ip>/<subfolder>/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/bigcircuits.jpg" alt="" />
```

I'd like to change that to using shortcode or something that can get the current siteurl from the database. Such as:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-60" title="bigcircuits" src="[getsiteurl]/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/bigcircuits.jpg" alt="" />
```

Is there something like that in a standard wordpress installation? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

I've fixed this in the past by using plugins such as exec-php which interprets php directly in the post (which gives you the power to use getbloginfo('siteurl') but i'd like a cleaner more customer-friendly approach.

I could code the shortcode myself i guess but i'd want to use standard functionality if it exists.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy solution to this. I normally dump the database to file, replace the old siteurl with the new and run that script in the target database.

Comment: i suspect you are right. it would be nice with something user friendly though since the client will be filling the website i've done with content himself in a subfolder on his own server before moving it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a filter ? [attachment_fields_to_save](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/attachment_fields_to_save) ... Applied to fields associated with an attachment prior to saving them in the database. So you can do a realy tiny pluggin for this and use it where you whant .

Comment: if i understand you correctly it doesn't solve the problem since the data would need to be replaced after the wordpress folder is moved anyway.

Comment: no, the wp-contet/uploads will remain the same, only domain name will change so you just have to strip domain name from the guid field before saving the attachemnt to db ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/aitch-ref/) to deal with that exact problem.  In it's settings page, just enter all the url of your dev and prod environment on new lines.  Give it a shot and let me know if you have any problems.